# How to cast wchar_t into int for displaying the code point?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, widestring, widechar

I have a simple function in my program, when I was wanting to mess around with unicode and do stuff with it. In this function, I wished to display the code value of the character the user entered. It SEEMED possible, here's my function:

```
wstring listcode(wchar_t arg) {
    wstring str = L"";
    str += static_cast<int> (arg); //I tried (int) arg as well
    str += L": ";
    str += (wchar_t) arg;
    return str;
}
```

Now as you see I just wanted to display the integer value (like an ascii character, such as `(int) "a"`), but something like `listcode(L"&")` will be displayed as `&: &` !

Is it not possible to find the integer value of a wide character like that?

Comment: I think you just shouldn't += an int to a wstring without converting it to a string representation.

Comment: It works fine returning just an int.

Comment: No, just convert (int)arg to a wstring before adding it to str (I don't know how to do that in C++ correctly).

Comment: @wRAR: But that's what the question is all about.

Comment: `wchar_t` does not always represent single code point. if `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 4 (on all POSIX platforms) then it represents one, but if `sizeof(wchar_t)` is 2 (on Windows) it does not as Unicode code point is in range 0-0x10FFFF which requires more then two bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, you cannot add anything to strings but characters and other strings. There is no implicit conversion from `int` (or anything else) to string. That's just the way the string type is designed.
What you do instead is to use string streams:

```
std::wstring listcode(wchar_t arg)
{
  std::wostringstream oss;
  oss << static_cast<int>(arg);
  oss << L": ";
  oss << arg;
  return oss.str();
}
```

In practice, however, when converting to strings in C++, it's better to have functions writing to a stream, than returning a string:

```
void listcode(std::wostream os, wchar_t arg)
{
  os << static_cast<int>(arg);
  os << L": ";
  os << arg;
}
```

That way, if you want to output something to the console or to a file, you can directly pass `std::cout` or a file stream, and if you want a string, you just pass a string stream.